# cannot resolve the symbol "path"

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect to the firebase database with my android app and i cannot use "path" keyword to get reference. It underlined it. I don't know why I am beginner to the Android and I have never used the firebase that why I don't know much about firebase database. Here is the code

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(fullName, age, email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( path: "Users")




                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: with path ... you can reference the location in your Database so that's basically where the data is stored or to be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java parameters don't have names, but instead are passed in the order in which they are needed. So:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
```

Comment: u saved me thanks a lot i really apricate it <3